# Multi-Module Project with Maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I run my project with idea, everything is ok.But When I use maven to package and run my project, I find that some module not updated. I got this error when I call a method which was added last week.

```
2022.05.30 at02:56:36.111 [traceId:,spanId:] ERROR org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog 182 log - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/xx/web/controller/PolicyManageController.syncCreatePolicyManage(Ljava/util/List;)Lcom/xx/xx/api/vo/base/BaseResponse; is abstract] with root cause java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/xx/web/controller/PolicyManageController.syncCreatePolicyManage(Ljava/util/List;)Lcom/xx/xx/api/vo/base/BaseResponse; is abstract
2022-05-30T02:56:36.122604768Z  at com.xx.xx.xx.web.controller.PolicyManageController.syncCreatePolicyManage(PolicyManageController.java) ~[xx-xx-web-1.0.0.20220524.030433-40.jar!/:?]
2022-05-30T02:56:36.122610640Z  at com.xx.xx.xx.api.rest.PolicyManageAPI$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$550d6744.invoke(<generated>) ~[xx-xx-api-1.0.1.SNAPSHOT.jar!/:?]
... ...
```

My local repository
[image: Local Repo]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us how your Maven project is structured? A minimal version of the POMs including the parents (if there is one) and **problematic** dependencies would be helpful.

Comment: Thks for your welcome. My Maven project has a parent named product, and has some sub module. api、assemble、biz、dal、web. I add the method in the biz